# Getting python script linked with C#

Tags: c#, python

I am using Visual Studio 2017 with NuGet packages: IronPython installed.

I need to be able to get the python script working in the C# application without an end user having to install python. I can get basic applications to run without any problem by just IronPython, then I tested with the library I needed for the script to work and it no longer worked with just IronPython and it would then need to point at my python Lib folder in order to get the libraries it needs. Is there any way around this or is the end user going to have no choice but to install python and the library on their computer to get my application to work?

Code for reference:

using IronPython.Hosting;

```
namespace testApp {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var py = Python.CreateEngine();
            try {
                py.ExecuteFile(@"python\test.py");
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + " - Error from visual studio");
            }

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Python:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r"C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib")  # points to python interpreter
import os
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

c = canvas.Canvas("Test.pdf")

c.drawString(100, 100, "This is some test text!")
c.showPage()
c.save()
```

Comment: In the python script, at the 2nd line you are referencing a python installation directory. How should it work without a proper python installation ?